# Как можно скрыть текст в кнопке при изменении размера окна

Tags: html, css

Когда страница "схлопывается" (адаптация для мобильных) как скрыть текст внутри кнопки и оставить только иконку?

```
<button class="btn" onclick=""><i class="icon-plus"></i>  Добавить форму</button>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ktLuto4w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Если допустимо использовать дополнительную обертку вокруг текста

```css
/* Для демонстрации */
.icon-plus {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* На мобильных устройствах (767px выбрано, чтобы работал пример) */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .btn span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="">
  <i class="icon-plus"></i>
  <span>Добавить форму</span>
</button>
```

#### Если использовать дополнительную разметку нельзя

```css
/* Для демонстрации */
.icon-plus {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* На больших устройствах (768px выбрано, чтобы работал пример)  */
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .btn::after {
    content: 'Добавить форму';
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Текст удален специально, он будет добавлен с помощью стилей -->
<button class="btn" onclick="">
  <i class="icon-plus"></i>
</button>
```

Нажмите на ссылку "На всю страницу" после запуска кода, чтобы появился текст на кнопке.

Answer (score 1):

Разверните на весь экран и текст появится, медиа выражение и картинку измените под себя.

```css
span {
  display: none;
}
.icon-plus {
  background: url(http://s.sk-gaming.com/image/member/9/0d7ae43aad8c6dd0m.jpg);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  span {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick=""><i class="icon-plus"></i><span>Добавить форму</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для Bootstrap 3 используйте класс `.hidden-xs`

Для Bootstrap 2 используйте класс `.hidden-phone`

```
<button type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="icon-save"></i> <span class="hidden-xs">Добавить форму</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

in media request:

```
. btn{

    font-size: 0 !important; 
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]